# Why can I see a deleted question while not having enough reputation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions

Cross-site duplicate of [View *my* deleted question and answer with less than 10K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125828/view-my-deleted-question-and-answer-with-less-than-10k).

At the time I'm writing this question, I have 9,041 reputation, which is [not enough to see deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

I just notice that I'm able to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59771456/how-do-you-delete-a-variable) deleted question.

Are you going to change the minimal requirement to see the deleted question or am I facing some bugs?

Comment: You've answered it, and you'll always be able to see your own posts.

Comment: @ivarni Yes, I know, but I now can see the deleted question too. Do you mean that as long as I answered a question, I'm able to see it even if it was deleted ?

Comment: Wouldn't make much sense to just see the answer, it's connected to the question.

Comment: This has always been the case; you can see your own answers on deleted questions, which can only work if you can see the deleted question.

Comment: Thank you guys for clarification, I never faced this case before and wasn't aware about that logic behind

Comment: Seems to be possible [since February 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179511).